# How to check if elements of list exists within list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1= ['paraben', 'alcohol','mica','talc','perfume']

products = [{'name': 'Product01', 'ingredients': 'Iron Oxides, Talc, Mica, Zinc Stearate, Dimethicone, Octyldodecyl Stearoyl Stearate, Maltodextrin'}
,{'name': 'Product02', 'ingredients': 'Octyldodecanol - Capric Triglyceride - Isononyl Isononanoate - Neopentyl Glycol Diethylhexanoate'}]
```

How can I check if one or more elements of the list1 does exist in values of the products, and print which list1 item exists in which product?

Result should look like this:
**#Product01 contains talc, mica.**

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that:

```
list1= ['paraben', 'alcohol','mica','talc','perfume']

products = [{'name': 'Product01', 'ingredients': 'Iron Oxides, Talc, Mica, Zinc Stearate, Dimethicone, Octyldodecyl Stearoyl Stearate, Maltodextrin'}
,{'name': 'Product02', 'ingredients': 'Octyldodecanol - Capric Triglyceride - Isononyl Isononanoate - Neopentyl Glycol Diethylhexanoate'}]

for d in products:
    name = d['name']
    from_list = list(filter(lambda x:x.lower() in list1,d['ingredients'].split(', ')))
    if from_list:
        print(f"{name} contains:",', '.join(from_list))
    else:
        print(f"{name} contains no ingredients from list")

#Result:
#Product01 contains: Talc, Mica
#Product02 contains no ingredients from list
```